# Android: Opening Activity with data with TabHost

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

My app is like this:

Tabhost:

- MapViewActivity
- ListViewActivity -> DetailActivity

In the DetailActivity there's a button to show something in the MapViewActivity. How do i close the DetailView and open the first tab **with** additional data, without loosing the tab hierarchy .

What i tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabsActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.putExtra(DATA_KEY, "some-data");
startActivity(intent);
```

But in the onResume in TabsActivity is wasn't able to retrieve the data from

```
getIntent();
```

So another option would be to set a listener and before finishing the Activity, notify the listener. But here the problem is that PutExtra wont take a Class as a value.

I think i'm not on the right track. So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following:

In the **ListViewActivity** i use **startActivityForResult();** like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, DetailActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

When i click a button, the **DetailActivity** sends the data back to **ListViewActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(KEY_ID, id);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Then i receive the data in **ListViewActivity** using the **onActivityResult()**:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == TrackDetailsActivity.REQUEST_CODE){
        String objectId = data.getStringExtra(DetailActivity.KEY_ID);
        if (objectId != null) {
            CustomTabActivity tabs = (CustomTabActivity)getParent();
            tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag(MapViewActivity.TAG);
            tabs.setObject(objectId);
        }
    } 

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

As you can see i store the result in my **CustomTabActivity**, later in **MapViewActivity** use this property.